# Java mysql syntax error

Tags: java, mysql, database

I get syntax error to mysql `insert` statement. May I know how to correct this error ?

```
user=txtuser.getText();
      char[] pass=jPasswordField1.getPassword();
             String passString=new String(pass);
            try{                
                Connection con = createConnection();               
                Statement st = con.createStatement();


**String sql = "INSERT INTO login(username,Password)"+"VALUES"+"('"user"','"passString"')";**
 st.executeUpdate(sql);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Exception: "+ e.toString());
            }
```

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery? Retagging now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing a few `+` operators:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO login(username,Password) VALUES ('" + user + "','" + passString + "')";
```

Consider using `PreparedStatement` placeholders to set these parameters. This will protect you from [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks also. Here is an [example](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/preparedstatement.html)

Comment: please can u tell how to use preparestatement

Comment: @user1966589 : http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/jdbc-mysql/TwicePreparedStatement.shtml

Comment: @limelights now i get a run time error . java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:Notyet implemented

Comment: From where? Make a new question and post your code and stacktrace or update this question with the stacktrace, please.